# Angular - [dateclass] error at mat-calendar

Tags: angular, angularjs

I'm trying to make a calendar where multiple date selections are possible. I found this source on  [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multi-date-picker?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

My code is the following for AppComponent:

```
isSelected = (event: any) => {
    const date = event as moment.Moment
    
    return (this.dates.find(x => x.isSame(date))) ? "selected": null;
  };
  
  select(event: any, calendar: any) {
    const date: moment.Moment = event

    const index = this.dates.findIndex(x => x.isSame(date));
    if (index < 0) this.dates.push(date);
    else this.dates.splice(index, 1);

    calendar.updateTodaysDate();
  }
```

And for my html :

```
<div class="col mx-3">
    <mat-card class="demo-inline-calendar-card">
      <h2 class="text-center">Reserveerbare datums</h2>
      <mat-calendar #calendar (selectedChange)="select($event,calendar)" [dateClass]="isSelected"></mat-calendar>
    </mat-card>
  </div>
```

1. I get the following error at [dateClass]:

   ```
   "Type '(event: any) => "selected" | null' is not assignable to type 'MatCalendarCellClassFunction<any>'"
   ```
2. When I click some date on my calendar another error pops up:

   ```
   "x.isSame is not a function"
   ```

Any help is appreciated. **Or if anyone got another approach to make this!**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
return (this.dates.find(x => x.isSame(date))) ? "selected" : "";
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multi-date-picker-c6kwgo?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thanks, you also know how to fix the isSame error?

Comment: Oh my! Thank you so much, I spend half the day trying to fix this! used multiple date picker libraries but kept getting errors. you sir are a genius! 9 years of experience in Front-End Well invested! Have a nice day!